# confusion in making of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

i am trying to understand a code of creating and displaying a linked list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int create(int n);
void print();

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}
*head=NULL;

int main(){
    int n,data;
    printf("Enter the Number of Nodes\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    create(n);
    print();
}

int create(int n){
    int i=1,data;
    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter element %d:\n",i++);
    scanf("%d",&data);
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
    head=temp;
    while(n-->1){
        struct node *t=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter element %d:\n",i++);
        scanf("%d",&data);
        t->data=data;
        t->next=NULL;
        temp->next=t;
        temp=t;
    }
    printf("Done :)\n");
}

void print(){
    struct node *temp=head;
    printf("Elements in list are:\n");
    if(temp==NULL)
        printf("List is Empty\n");
    else
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Now, i understand most of the working but there is some confusion I wanted to clarify.

The first node is created as head.the second node as t, which is then connected to head by pointing the next of head to itself. then how does the third node know that we are connecting it to second node(because all nodes are named t). is it because of `temp = t` at the end of the while loop, so at next run the new t node gets connected to the temp which is previous t node.

If that is the case, then I assume that only addresses are being connected to each other.

More precisely, with malloc we assign a memory of `data` and `next` to temp(which is pointer to node) then put first element in `data` and NULL in `next` and that is our first node. after that we have a head pointer which points to this first node.

My real confusion is what is happening is that we create new address bunches with each loop run and the `print()` uses those addresses to iterate from head to the last node. **and exept `head` there is nothing to access our linked list after we exit the function.**

**CORRECT?**

the terminology may not be to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the third node gets connected to the second by the statement temp->next=t (temp has the address of second and 't' is a new node) and at last, you are making temp=t so in next iteration, the temp will have third node address and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> is it because of temp = t at the end of the while loop, so at next run the new t node gets connected to the temp which is previous t node.

Yes. `temp` keeps track of the latest node.

`struct node *next` holds the memory location of the next node.

> and except head there is nothing to access our linked list after we exit the function.

Yes. Without knowing `head`, you wont be able to go through your list.